# Find largest Dictionary<int,string> key whose value is less than the search value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have `Dictionary<int,string>` with ascending keys like this:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int,string>
{
    {750,"one"},
    {1500,"two"},
    {2500,"three"},
    {5000,"four"},
    {10000,"five"},
    {25000,"six"}
}
```

I have `var myValue = 3000.52`

I need to find the largest `myDictionary` key that is smaller than my value. In this case, I need to return 2500.

I have tried:

```
foreach (var key in myDictionary.Keys.Where(key => key <= myValue))
{

}
```

But, as you would expect, all smaller values also match.

How do I find the largest key that is smaller than my search value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using LinQ is the simplest way I think:

```
int myKey = myDictionary.Where(x => x.Key < myValue)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
                        .First().Key;
```

Comment: I figured there was an easy way. I am a beginner with LinQ, I obviously need to change that.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a `List<int>` from the dictionary keys. I would store this list if you need to lookup it often. Then you can use [`List.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the nearest key:

```
int key = 3000;
var keys = new List<int>(myDictionary.Keys);
// keys.Sort(); if it was not already sorted
var index = keys.BinarySearch(key);
if (index >= 0)
{
    // dictionary contains this key
}
else
{
    int nextSmaller = ~index - 1;
    string valueOfNextSmaller = myDictionary[keys[nextSmaller]]; // three
}
```

`BinarySearch` returns the zero-based index of item in the **sorted** `List<T>`, if item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise complement of the index of the next element that is larger than item or, if there is no larger element, the bitwise complement of Count.

Answer (score 1):

Giorgos' answer is the best you'll be able to do working with `Dictionary`, but it will be slow because this will search the entire keyspace. If you want something fast, the C5 collections library has a lot of features lacking in .NET. You can do this:

```
TreeDictionary<K,V> dict;
var last = dict.RangeTo(myValue).Backwards().First();
```

Which will execute in O(log n), much more efficient as your dictionary's size grows.

Comment: This is good to know, but I don't believe this Dictionary will grow beyond 20 items

Answer (score 0):

You can use an integer to keep track of the highest.

```
int temp = 0;
foreach (var key in myDictionary.Keys)
{
    if (key > temp) { temp = key; }
}
if (searchvalue > temp) { // invalidate search}
//Do something with temp here.
```

Comment: this does not take the search value into account

Comment: I added a short piece of code. But I'm not sure what you want to do with the search value. The highest value in the dictionary will always be the highest value. The only thing is is what happens when the highest value is lower than the search value.

Comment: the OP wants the highest value that is *less* than the search value, so the overall highest value might not qualify